# Installation of package 'glmnet' had Non-Zero Exit Status

Tags: r, glmnet

I've been trying to install the **glmnet** package in my R server (version 3.6.0) however it returns the following error message:

```
> install.packages("glmnet")      
Installing package into ‘/home/my@email.net/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)        
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/glmnet_4.1-3.tar.gz'          
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2318567 bytes (2.2 MB)           
==================================================    
downloaded 2.2 MB   
             
* installing *source* package ‘glmnet’ ...        
** package ‘glmnet’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked        
** using staged installation        
** libs        
g++  -I"/usr/include/R" -DNDEBUG  -I"/home/my@email.net/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/RcppEigen/include" 
-I"/home/my@email.net/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/Rcpp/include" -I/usr/local/include -Iglmnetpp/include
-Iglmnetpp/src -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o        

RcppExports.cpp:127:122: error: ‘>>’ should be ‘> >’ within a nested template argument list                
 List spwls_exp(double alm0, double almc, double alpha, int m, int no, int ni, const Eigen::Map<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> x,
 const Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> xm, const Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> xs, Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> r, Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> xv, 
 const Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> v, int intr, const Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXi> ju, const Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> vp, 
 const Eigen::Map<Eigen::MatrixXd> cl, int nx, double thr, int maxit, Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> a, double aint, Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXd> g,
 Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXi> ia, Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXi> iy, int iz, Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXi> mm, int nino, double rsqc, int nlp, int jerr);    
                                                                                                                              
RcppExports.cpp: In function ‘SEXPREC* _glmnet_spwls_exp(SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP,
SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP, SEXP)’:
RcppExports.cpp:138:79: error: ‘>>’ should be ‘> >’ within a nested template argument list
     Rcpp::traits::input_parameter< const Eigen::Map<Eigen::SparseMatrix<double>> >::type x(xSEXP);
                                                                            
make: *** [RcppExports.o] Error 1                
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘glmnet’        
* removing /home/my@email.net/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/3.6/glmnet’        
Warning in install.packages :        
  installation of package ‘glmnet’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmp4ICF5H/downloaded_packages’
```

Can anyone advise on why I am getting the above error? I have tried installing the package with and without the dependencies too.

If it's useful, my sessioninfo() is as follows:

```
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)  Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/R/lib/libRblas.so
locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Matrix_1.2-17 ROracle_1.3-1 DBI_1.1.1    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.6.0  tools_3.6.0     grid_3.6.0      lattice_0.20-38`
```

Any advice would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: Probably best to update your old R first, current version is 4.1.2 .

Comment: there seem to be a [handful of related errors in other Rcpp-using installs](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Rcpp%22+error:+%E2%80%98%3E%3E%E2%80%99+should+be+%E2%80%98%3E+%3E%E2%80%99+within+a+nested+template+argument+list)